# Python subplot used to show one figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, spyder

When I was using the subplot, and tried to use the following subplot to plot only one figure, it will give error:

> AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'flat'

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols,figsize=figsize)
for i, ax in enumerate(ax.flat):
    ax.plot(X, Y, color='k')
```

How to solve this issue if I want to **arbitrarily set the number of sub figures**?How can I easily understand `ax.flat`?

Comment: Why don’t you use enumerate(ax)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flat` is an attribute of `numpy` arrays which returns an iterator. For example, if you have a 2d array like this:

```
import numpy as np
arr2d = np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2)
arr2d
# array([[0, 1],
#        [2, 3]])
```

the `flat` attribute is provided as a convenient way to iterate through this array as if it was a 1d array:

```
for value in arr2d.flat:
    print(value)
# 0
# 1
# 2
# 3
```

You can also flatten the array with the `flatten` method:

```
arr2d.flatten()
# array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

So going back to your question, when you specify:

- `ncols` to 1 and `nrows` to a value greater than 1 or the other way around, you get the axes in a 1d numpy array, in which case the `flat` attribute returns the same array.
- both `ncols` and `nrows` to values greater than 1, you get the axes in a 2d array, in which case the `flat` attribute returns the flattened array.
- both `ncols` and `nrows` to 1, you get the axes object, which doesn't have a `flat` attribute.

So a possible solution would be to turn your `ax` object into a `numpy` array everytime:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=figsize)

ax = np.array(ax)
for i, axi in enumerate(ax.flat):
    axi.plot(...)
```

Answer (score 6):

There is precisely one case where the code

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols,figsize=figsize)
for i, ax in enumerate(ax.flat):
    ax.plot(X, Y, color='k')
```

would not work as expected. This is for `nrows = ncols = 1`. This is because for one single row and column, `ax` is a single subplot, not an array of several subplots.

To circumvent this problem, and to be able to use the same code without knowing `nrows` and `ncols` in advance, use the **`squeeze=False`** option. This will ensure `ax` is always an array and hence has a `.flat` attribute. For better understandability don't call the axes array by the same name as the axes itself.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, squeeze=False, figsize=figsize)
for i, ax in enumerate(axs.flat):
    ax.plot(X, Y, color='k')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a set of subplots having multiple rows/columns with the command `fig,ax=plt.subplots()`, it returns a `fig` and a list of axes `ax`. The shape of `ax` list is 2 dimensions (rows, cols). That is the reason why you need to flatten it to become 1 dimension when you iterate the `ax` list. To get access to a specific axes, you need the row/column indices, for example, ax[r][c] is the axes on (r+1)th row/ (c+1)th column. The indices are zero based. The working code below demonstrate how to do it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

nrows,ncols = 3,2
figsize = [5,9]
X = np.random.rand(6)
Y = np.random.rand(6)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=figsize)
for i, axi in enumerate(ax.flat):
    axi.plot(X, Y, color='k')
    rowid = i // ncols
    colid = i % ncols
    axi.set_title("row:"+str(rowid)+",col:"+str(colid))

# You can access the axes by row_id, col_id.
# Now let's plot on ax[row_id][col_id] of your choice
ax[0][1].plot(Y,X,color='red')    # plot 2nd line in red
ax[2][0].plot(Y,X,color='green')  # plot 2nd line in green

plt.tight_layout(True)
plt.show()
```

The output plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `ax.ravel()` or `ax.flatten()`. Below is a simple example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3, figsize=(8, 6))

# for i, ax in enumerate(ax.flatten()):
for i, ax in enumerate(ax.ravel()):
    ax.plot([1,2,3], color='k')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @Gamp: Yes, because there you have just a single axis